# How can I designate that one project is a subset of another?

Tags: gradle

So I have a `contracts` project and a `artifacts` project. `artifacts` just adds a few classes to contracts which itself is strictly WSDL/WADL generation. I want to depend on only one of these which means that `contracts` needs to be treated like a subset of `artifacts`. In a nutshell, what I think I should see is all the class files generated in `contracts` should show up in both the jar file and build/classes/main.  Is there a dependency based way to do this or am I stuck with a plain old copy task?

Of course, I might be barking up the wrong tree. Can I specify a dependency on a project's artifacts that will cause the contents (preferably) or the jar itself (if I have to) to always be included? What syntax for that?

Comment: Why are they organized as separate projects in the first place, instead of separate packages in the same project? You can solve this in 2 ways: You can include the source folders of artifact projects into contracts sourceset, or you can use a custom jar task (or the shadow plugin) to package artifact classes into contracts jar.

Comment: XML generation as noted below.

Comment: Hmmm.... skip the *.class file generation in contracts and include the *.java source set in javaCompile for artifacts? That could be just the ticket. I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: Yes, but you dont even have to define a javaCompile task, you can add any arbitrary directory to look for .java files to an existing project. I'll add an answer for both approaches I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for including one project as a dependency of another project is:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':<project>')
    ...
}
```

This supposes that the gradle build is set up with a `settings.gradle` containing all the sub-projects. So to have one project depending on another, `settings.gradle` would contain:

```
include 'project1'
include 'project2'
```

and if you wanted project2 to depend on project1 you would include:

```
compile project(':project1')
```

in the build.gradle file for project2.

Comment: I want project 1 to literally include project 2. If I use a standard dependency like this, I end up with a project that depends on another jar project rather than ending up with a project that literally includes another project. For example, the jar file of project 2 will not contain files from project 1. I did figure out how to do this in the jar task but then my build fails. I assume it's because gradle doesn't depend on jars like maven does.

Comment: What do you mean by *literally include*? Are you talking about packing project2 classes inside project1 jar? Also, why are you trying to do that? Modularity is generally good.

Comment: I mean that project 2 is a subset of project 1. It's impossible to use project 2 without project 1. The reason we want them separate is because project 2 represents a lot of XML generation. That's a good reason but it's a build-only reason. Note that maven is doing exactly this. It builds the XML in project 2, then project 1 builds an aggregate and subprojects depend on project 1 only.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Add source from second project into sourceSet

In a gradle java project, it is possible to add any arbitrary directory as a source location. So if your structure looks like this:

```
├───ProjA
│   └───src
│       └───main
│           └───java
└───ProjB
    └───src
        └───main
            └───java
```

You could add projB's source into projA's sourceset. Of course you'd be breaking gradle convention, and you have to be conscious of breaking paths if you move folders, but in ProjA's build.gradle, you could do:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDir "$rootDir/../ProjB/src/main/java"
```

This will add the specified directory to sourceSet used during compile and the resulting .class files will be included in the jar artifacts you create.

You could continue to build projB separately, but it doesn't really matter whether you do or not.

#### 2. Add second project as a dependency and create an "uberJar" artifact

In projA build.gradle, you add projB as a compile time dependency, either as a project `compile project(':projB')` as a jar dependency `compile 'mygroup:projB:1.0'`

At artifact creation time, you can either use the [gradle shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) or add an uberjar task, to unpack all dependencies and include the classes and resources in the jar you produce.

```
task uberJar(type: Jar) {
    //collect all dependencies
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```